# Microsoft Teams Splash Screen Stays Open

Tags: microsoft-teams

The Microsoft Teams splash screen stays open all the time.

How can I get it to close after Teams starts up?

[image: Microsoft Teams Splash Screen]

Comment: Well I uninstalled and reinstalled, but the problem came back

Answer (score 3):

I have exactly same problem. I believe that, in my case it was because I enabled NVidia's desktop manager. Microsoft might be hiding the splash screen outside virtual desktop area and NVidia desktop manager always brings it back to the viewable area of the desktop.

Comment: This worked for me. I could simply disable teams from NVidia's desktop manager and viola. Problem solved.

Comment: +1 @Ghlouw.  My click path was like this (for what it's worth; yours may be different):   On desktop, right-click > menu item "nView Desktop Manager" >   left-tree item "Applications" > button "Add" > click "Application" and "Class" buttons for "Find" (then click and drag the target icon over the Teams "Launching App" window) > then button "Disable" > uncheck the top-level checkbox > "OK"

Answer (score -3):

I have been personally using Microsoft Teams in my organization and it works fine every time i run it.

Check your network speed or computer memory usage from the task manager and see if there are some extra services running behind. You better close them.

Comment: I have an developer laptop (i7 quad, ssd, 32 gb ram) and an 100mb connection to the internet.